# How to keep an app always active on screen

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions, controls

I'm developing a peculiar application which need to prevent the user can go out from application Activities, except with the ways I established inside the application. The Clock in tablet status bar for example allows to go in Android Settings, and I want to prevent it... because I need only some "device administrators" can access to android settings and other apps, others people must can only use this app.

There is a SDK solution?

PS I need to restrict capabilities only to device owner to prevent accidentally damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope nothing within the public APIs will allow you to do this. I understand that there are legit use cases for it, but to have it possible on all devices would create significant security concerns. (i.e. malicious apps could "lock out" users from their own devices.)

The closest you can get is create a replacement home screen that does not give the user the ability to (easily) go anywhere except where you want.

However as you've noticed with the settings in notification bar there are still loopholes around this. Another of such loopholes is many android keyboards contain a button that will take you to settings.

Also the user may still start their device in "safe mode" which would disable your application.

If you wish to implement this and have it be 100% effective you'd have to modify the OS to allow for it.

Comment: Infact I have developed it as a Homescreen, thinking to resolve the problem, but just now I noticed, the Android Settings Button in notification bar. Unfortunately, each tablet device must be used by many inexpert people, and I need to restrict capabilities only to device owner to prevent accidentally damage. :/ The safe mode, is not a problem, because I need to protect the device from accidentally damage, not from malicious damage :)

Comment: @Eghes If they start the device in safe mode I believe there will be nothing stopping them from going into the settings, which seems like what you are trying to prevent.

Comment: Yes, but to start the device in safe mode, is required the will of user to break the device. But I need only to protect the device from inexpert users, which could accidentally damage the device, accessing to android settings(unwittingly).

Comment: @Eghes: You still have no choice but to create a custom ROM. Android is a consumer operating system, designed to put the put control of the device in the hands of the device user. You are welcome to try to steal control, such as blocking access to Settings, but the operating system will actively try to prevent it. Creating your own custom ROM is the expected solution here.

Comment: I understood, but is needed a custom ROM for each tablet model... therefore I searched for a SDK solution...